# Python Return Syntax Error

Tags: python

```
def list_function(x):
    return x[1] += 3
```

I want to do this, but apparently I can't. I understand I can do this

```
x[1] += 3
return x
```

but, I wanted to keep it on a single line. Does return always need to be on its own line, and if not, why does it need to be in this particular case?

Comment: The problem is not the return, but rather that `x[1] += 3` is not an expression, it's a complete statement and thus belongs to its own line

Comment: Ah, that was my suspicion, but I was hoping something like this could get around that `return (x[1] += 3)`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As a side note, `return x[1] += 3;` is valid C code, but it's equivalent to `x[1] += 3; return x[1];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an arbitrary expression after the return statement, i.e. something that yields a value to be returned.  Assignment, including augmented assignments like `x[1] += 3`, are not expressions in Python.  They are statements, and as such don't yield a value, so they can't be used after `return`.

If you insist on having everything on a single line, you can of course write

```
x[1] += 3; return x
```

However, I can't see any valid reason to do so.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I agree with you on the last part. That's technically one line, but not what I meant and I believe you understood that.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

> return_stmt ::=  "return" [expression_list]

The return statement can only be followed by expressions. [`expression_list`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list) is -

> expression_list ::=  expression ( "," expression )* [","]

But `x[1] += 1` is an [augmented assignment **statement**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) , and as such you cannot have that after `return` .